# User with unique To_do_list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am doing an app with `User, Article and To_do_list`

I am using the gem bookmark_system to add a bookmark to an article. 
https://github.com/pmviva/bookmark_system

The list of the bookmarked articles is what I am going to show in the To_do_list.

I want each user to have only 1 To_do_list. I also want users to be able to check other users to_do_list.

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
act_as_bookmarker
has_many :articles
has_one :to_do_list
end
```

article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
act_as_bookmarkee
end
```

to_do_list:

```
class ToDoList < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

to_do_lists_controller.rb:

```
class ToDoListsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles_bookmark = current_user.bookmarkees_by(Article)
  end
```

the migration:

```
class ToDoLists < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :to_do_lists do |t|
  t.belongs_to :user, index: { unique: true }, foreign_key: true
  end
  end
end
```

The schema:

```
create_table "to_do_lists", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
  add_index "to_do_lists", ["user_id"], name: "index_to_do_lists_on_user_id", unique: true
```

Routes:

```
  resources :to_do_lists
```

The paths:

```
to_do_lists GET      /to_do_lists(.:format)          to_do_lists#index                           
POST                 /to_do_lists(.:format)          to_do_lists#create                                               
new_to_do_list GET   /to_do_lists/new(.:format)      to_do_lists#new                                         
edit_to_do_list GET  /to_do_lists/:id/edit(.:format) to_do_lists#edit                                       
to_do_list GET       /to_do_lists/:id(.:format)      to_do_lists#show                                           
PATCH                /to_do_lists/:id(.:format)      to_do_lists#update                                       
PUT                  /to_do_lists/:id(.:format)      to_do_lists#update                                      
DELETE               /to_do_lists/:id(.:format)      to_do_lists#destroy
```

I am confused with 2 things:

1 - the user will need to "create" a to_do_list, but I don't want the user to create it, I want it to be created already and only show items if the user bookmarked something.

2 - To make a user to access other user is also causing me some questions, perhaps this can be clearer once I figure out the point above.

Please give me some lights as I am a bit lost here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended realising that that I already have the data that I want to show available and dont actually need to create any controller etc.

Instead for this situation I created the methods in the user_controller and then created the routes to show what I wanted.

The to_do_list controller would make sense if I wanted the users to create tasks in the to_do_list.